# Camera Rotation using AxisAngleRotation3D

Tags: c#, rotation, transform, kinect-sdk

I am working on camera rotation (NOT Geometry rotation) using kinect v2 sdk 2.0
Can anyone please guide me which method would be better to find the vector about which rotation is required OR to use quaternions?
And I am getting some weird rotations in my application using this code:

```
double sum = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(rotX, 2) + Math.Pow(rotY, 2) + Math.Pow(rotZ, 2));
static double rotX = 0;
static double rotY = 0;
static double rotZ = 0;
static RotateTransform3D trRot = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(rotX, rotY, rotZ), 0));
if (gesture == GestureRecognition.rotation.ClockwiseYaw)
{
    myCamera.Transform = trRot;
    trRot.Rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(rotX / sum, rotY / sum, -rotZ / sum), rotZ -= 5);
    if (rotZ == 360)
    {
        rotZ = 0;
    }
}
else if (gesture == GestureRecognition.rotation.CounterClockwiseYaw)
{
    myCamera.Transform = trRot;
    trRot.Rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(rotX / sum, rotY / sum, -rotZ / sum), rotZ += 5);
    if (rotZ == 360)
    {
        rotZ = 0;
    }
}
else if (gesture == GestureRecognition.rotation.ClockwisePitch)
{
    myCamera.Transform = trRot;
    trRot.Rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(rotX / sum, -rotY / sum, rotZ / sum), rotY -= 5);
    if (rotY == 360)
    {
        rotY = 0;
    }
}
else if (gesture == GestureRecognition.rotation.CounterClockwisePitch)
{
    myCamera.Transform = trRot;
    trRot.Rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(rotX / sum, -rotY / sum, rotZ / sum), rotY += 5);
    if (rotY == 360)
    {
        rotY = 0;
    }
}
else if (gesture == GestureRecognition.rotation.TiltUp)
{
    myCamera.Transform = trRot;
    trRot.Rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(-rotX / sum, rotY / sum, rotZ / sum), rotX += 5);
    if (rotX == 360)
    {
        rotX = 0;
    }
}
else if (gesture == GestureRecognition.rotation.TiltDown)
{
    myCamera.Transform = trRot;
    trRot.Rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(-rotX / sum, rotY / sum, rotZ / sum), rotX -= 5);
    if (rotX == 360)
    {
        rotX = 0;
    }
}
else if (gesture == GestureRecognition.rotation.NothingRecognized)
{
    myCamera.Position = new Point3D(myCamera.Position.X, myCamera.Position.Y, myCamera.Position.Z);
}
```